# Trying to save as Object Array but keeps getting saved as Array of Array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement an interface to make it easier to post data to my database. A user can select multiple products and when they go back to search for more products the page is refreshed so I have to keep the products in local storage until they checkout.

Before I tried to implement the interface each additional product would just get stored as an object inside the array. After trying to implement the interface the first product is an object and the rest are array of array objects

AddItem.ts

```
name: string = this.navParams.get('name');
desc: string = this.navParams.get('desc');

saveItem() {

    let newItem = {
      name: this.name,
      desc: this.desc
    };

    this.dataStorageService.save(newItem).then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.pop(Search);
    });
}
```

DataStorageService.ts

```
save(data): Promise<any> {
 return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
  if (products) {
    products.push(data);
    return this.storage.set('products', products);
  }
  return this.storage.set('products', [data]);
});
}
```

How the objects get stored in localstorage

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to do now

Order.Interface.ts

```
export interface Order {
  name: string;
  desc: string;
}
```

AddItem.ts

```
name: string = this.navParams.get('name');
desc: string = this.navParams.get('desc');

orders = [] as Order[];

saveItem(): void {

this.orders.push({name: this.name, desc: this.desc});

this.dataStorageService.save(this.orders).then(() => {

});
```

DataStorageService.ts

```
save(data): Promise<any> {

   return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
   if (products) {
     products.push(data);
     return this.storage.set('products', products);
   }
   return this.storage.set('products', data);
   });
}
```

How the products are getting stored

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `products.push(data)`

Instead I would say you need to do this

```
save(data): Promise<any> {

   return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
   if (products) {
     products = products.concat(data);
     return this.storage.set('products', products);
   }
   return this.storage.set('products', data);
   });
}
```

also for better type checking you can change the method to this

`save(data : Order[]): Promise<any> {`